# How to close a tty

Tags: arch-linux, tty, systemd

I've opened several ttys and I don't know the key combination to use to close a tty. I'm using Arch Linux.

Comment: You didn't open them, they're open.  You just changed VT. If you want to log out from one of them, use `exit`.  If you are not logged in, don't worry.  It was there before, just you weren't looking at it.

Comment: @goldilocks, VTs can be dynamically allocated and closed. The first one is always allocated when the console is on it, `init` and X generally allocate the next ones, but you can allocate more. Opening the `/dev/ttyx` device is enough to allocate it.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas : Fair enough.  I was just inferring from "using key combinations" that ngwdaniel actually did not start anything that init hadn't spawned already.  If so, there's no need to close those (and as you point out in your answer, that's not so easily done anyway).

Comment: You meant reduce the count of available tty?

Comment: @goldilocks thank you, this is the answer I was looking for. I'm a silly beginner and I thought it was me who opened the ttys by <Alt> + <F2> etc

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## "Closing" a TTY

- If `systemd` is not the `init` being used then this **will not** help you.
- `sysvinit` is **no longer** supported by **Arch Linux**

`systemd`'s `systemctl` is used to control all the `service units` on the system. To learn more about it reference `man systemd.unit`. Stopping the `getty` service on the desired `tty` will perform the task in question. Below is the command to perform this action and I've also added a test so you can comfirm the results.

`# systemctl stop getty@ttyX.service`

- Replace `X` with the `tty` number *you* would like to close

  - *If **[F4]** was used to switch to the `tty` then the service is named `getty@tty4.service`.*
- This procedure **will also close all** applications/clients ran from the specified `tty`.

#### Test

1. Switch to `tty4` and enter your `username` and `password`.

   - `<CTRL>+<ALT>+[F4]`
2. Launch *your* favorite text editor

   - `vim foo.bar`
3. Switch back to `tty1` or whichever `tty` you were originally in

   - `<CTRL>+<ALT>+[F1]`
4. Open a terminal window and check if `vim` is running

   - `pgrep vim`

     - `pgrep` returns the **signal process** number of the specified application. Multiple numbers will be returned if there are multiple instances of the same application

       - *(if there are four terminal windows open then `pgrep` will output four process numbers)*
5. As root **stop** the `getty` service for `tty4`

   - `# systemctl stop getty@tty4.service`
6. Recheck if `vim` is still active on `tty4` where it was opened and editing `foo.bar`

   - `pgrep vim` *(if there is no output/less output than in step 4, then there is no process)*
7. Double check the status of the `getty@.service` for `tty4`

   - `systemctl status getty@tty4.service | grep -i "Active"`

     - Piping the output to `grep -i "Active"` will only output the required line that you'll need to observe to confirm the `getty` has been **disabled**

       - `Active: inactive (dead)`

Comment: u can use `who` command to list currently logged users and tty numbers.

Answer (score 7):

I believe it's the `deallocvt` command you're looking for.

First make sure the VT is no longer used. For instance, if there's a `getty` started with *respawning* by `init` on that console, there's no point trying to deallocate it, you'd need to remove that tty from the `inittab` first and tell `init` to reload its config. If there's a shell, exit the shell, etc.